# sql server Trigger Implicit order?

Tags: sql-server-2005, triggers

I have 2 Triggers on a table : `Tr1` , `Tr2` .

I **didn't** set order to any.

*my question :*

If I set to `Tr1` [sp_settriggerorder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186762.aspx)  with "`first`" value.

Does it say `implicitly` that `Tr2` will be the `second` one `automatically`?

`Or` should I also use sp_settriggerorder  with "last" value to the Other Trigger ?

Comment: What would be the only sensible implementation of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martin Smith alludes in his comment.  If you only have two triggers and one has been designated as first.  Then the remaining trigger **has** to fire second.  That is proper application of ordering when you have two triggers.

For a very thorough explanation of trigger ordering [read this article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1409/forcing-trigger-firing-order-in-sql-server/)

but in summary...

- If you have 2 triggers you only need to designate a first OR a last to ensure a firing order.
- If you have 3 triggers you must designate BOTH a first and a last to ensure firing order.  The third trigger won't have an order but since it's the only one left it automatically gets fired 2nd.
- If you have four or more triggers, you may designate a first and a last but the others will fire in an arbitrary order somewhere in the middle.  *You may also want to have a 'pshrink' on retainer if you regularly have four or more triggers on a table.*